# How do I detect the current background color of the terminal in which my python script was invoked?

Tags: python, text, colors, xterm

I am using a xfce4 terminal and I want to be able to detect if the background color is set to either black or white (or presumably some other color)

My code looks like this:

```
def print_color(string, style, textColor, background):  
     string = "\033[{};{};{}m{}\033[m ".format(style,textColor,background,string)  
     print(string)
```

I would like to detect the current background color and use it instead of passing it in.

I've tried not setting it, like this:

```
def print_color(string, style, textColor):  
     string = "\033[{};{};m{}\033[m ".format(style,textColor,string)  
     print(string)
```

but that did not work as I expected.

Comment: xfce4 is built with the GTK+ toolkit. You could check the GTK+ toolkits Python language binding, and see if there's a way you can use that library - https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

XFCE4 terminal uses VTE, which lacks the ability to respond to queries of the colors.  That would be the SGR flavor of [DECRQSS](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Device-Control-functions:DCS-$-q-Pt-ST.DF5), which is mostly unimplemented in VTE.

(The example shown wouldn't work anyway).  This is unrelated to the GTK+ toolkit.